# load different html in the current page without reloading/refreshing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, single-page-application

i was looking at this website and i am interested on how did the developer managed to load different htmls in a single page without the current page being reloaded...

here is the website: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/validator/index.html...

for example if you clicked globalization in the Framework section, you can see the url changed, the body changed also but a part of the page remains (the top part) and the current page is not reloaded...

i am just starting in web development and i want to know this technique... i hope you can share it to me.... thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is using ajax partial updates. You send request to the server and get portion of the page and then place it in some element, for example in div.

Normal:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <head>
   <body>
      <div id="divToUpdate"></div>
      @Ajax.ActionLink("Call Partial", "MyAction", "MyController", AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" })
   <body>
</html>
```

Partial:

```
 <span> here is my partial view which will be placed in "divToUpdate" div after clicking "Call Partial" Link </span>
```

Comment: why do we use Partial views in ajax partial page update? what is the problem in using "normal" views? as i understand it, you call the address of the partial view and display it in an element like div. but can i call the address of normal views instead?

Comment: Difference in partial and normal views is that partial views are segment of code. For example, there are head and body tags in normal views, in partial views there are not. See Update